# Dynamically generate table in form using Ajax with symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am working with symfony project . I want to generate  table in form when select some option in the form.

This is my task.

There is name options in the form ( eg. John , Mia , Lia .. etc)
When we select "John" . I want to display  all detail about "john" using table.
that table should be locate in form .

There is some example is in this  link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

But i want to do that using symfony.

What is the best way do this.

Please mention some example.

using Javascript , Jquery or ajax with Symfony

Comment: Tell us what you tried, and where you are failing.

Answer (score 2):

The Symfony keyword is misleading here because you would generate the table from the client javascript code. In your javascript you initiate an Ajax call which post a request to your PHP/Symfony application. The one returns a JSON array of objects, and your Ajax complete/done method create the table using jQuery for example. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready (function () {

    }) ;

    function go () {
        $.post ('/index.php/api/mycall',
        //$.post ('/php.php',
            {
                "param1": "param1",
                "param2": 2
            })
            .done (function (ret) {
                var tbl =$('#mytable') ;
                tbl.empty () ;
                $(document.createElement('tr'))
                    .append ('<th>id</th><th>firstname</th><th>lastname</th>')
                    .appendTo (tbl) ;
                $.each (ret, function (index, val) {
                    $(document.createElement('tr'))
                        .append ('<td>' + val.id + '</td><td>' + val.firstname + '</td><td>' + val.lastname + '</td>')
                        .appendTo (tbl) ;
                }) ;
            }) ;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="go()" />
    <div id="mytable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And somewhere in your symphony code where you handle the post query for /api/mycall

```
$results =[
  (object)[
    "id" => 1,
    "firstname" => "John",
    "lastname" => "Doe"
  ],
  (object)[
    "id" => 2,
    "firstname" => "Jane",
    "lastname" => "Doe"
  ]
] ;
return (new JsonResponse ($results, Response::HTTP_OK)) ;
```

Hope that helps